# Elegant version of %in% in R that returns NA?

Tags: r

So, I was surprised by the behavior of the third line of this R code:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, 5, 6, 7, 8)
ifelse(x < 4, 1, 0)
ifelse(x %in% 1:3, 1, 0)
```

It returns `1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0` not the `1,1,1,0,NA,0,0,0,0` that I assumed I would get, ie the same as the second line.  Closer inspection of the helpfile for `%in%` and `match` shows this is documented behavior, returning:

> "A logical vector, indicating if a match was located for each element of x: thus the values are TRUE or FALSE and never NA."

Is there a general function that is similar to `%in%` except that it would give an NA in this circumstance?  For instance, this returns the desired result:

```
`%inna%` <- function(x, table){
  y <- match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0
  y[is.na(x)] <- NA
  return(y)
}

ifelse(x %inna% 1:3, 1, 0)
```

But is there a common way of doing this?

Comment: I think akrun has it covered, but if I was code-golfing you could abuse that `==` returns `NA` and do: `tab <- 1:3; x == tab[1] | x %in% tab`

Comment: You should use `as.integer` instead of `ifelse` or preferably create a logical vector as result.

Comment: @Roland that sounds sensible and a bit simpler but is there a particular other reason/pitfall too that it avoids?

Comment: `ifelse` is just a terrible, inefficient function. Its only saving grace is that it makes it very obvious what the code is intended to achieve. But so does `as.integer` in this case. However, it is only necessary to explicitly coerce logical values to integer values (R will do the coercion automatically if necessary), if you need that for display (e.g., in a plot) or export.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can replace with `NA` by either multiplying `NA` generated using `is.na(x)`

```
(x %in% 1:3) * NA^(is.na(x))
#[1]  1  1  1  0 NA  0  0  0  0
```

---

Or use `replace`

```
replace(+(x %in% 1:3), is.na(x), NA)
#[1]  1  1  1  0 NA  0  0  0  0
```

---

It can be converted to a function

```
`%inna%` <- function(x, table) {
      replace(as.integer(x %in% table), is.na(x), NA)
 }

x %inna% 1:3
#[1]  1  1  1  0 NA  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks, and I'll probably accept this as the answer.  But what I take from this is that I wasn't missing something obvious, and the tidy solution (because I have to do this many times and readability is the priority) is to create a function like `%inna%` (whether my definition or yours, they both do the same thing)?

Comment: @PeterEllis My code is based on your `ifelse` statement.  It does the same thing.  Regarding the readability, it depends on the user.  For me, both are equally useful